# jQuery smooth scroll for WordPress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've been trying to make my links work on my theme I am creating but I have no knowledge of jQuery for the smooth scrolling. In my theme I used the following jQuery I saw was working online:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

In my dynamic WordPress menu I set the urls to #values, #about, #contact etc. and the links to it on the specific places on the page I used `<span id="values"></span>, <span id="about"></span> and <span id="contact"></span>`

It works, but the smooth scrolling doesn't work. I see that anchors are used for smooth scrolling online in the parts of the page but I want to be able to target the id of the span tags. I tried to make an anchor tag to test if it works but it still doesn't.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: wat is the value of `this.hash`? Shouldn't that line be `$(this).attr('href');`

Comment: The snippet you provided is working nominally here: https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/6nbx2waf/ Please provide link to the site. What does the console say?

Comment: @Miro exactly. I don't understand. The theme is on my localhost, sorry. Should I zip it and share it on my drive? The console says "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

Comment: In Wordpress you need to add extrenal jquery or equate the dollar sign to the one already in use. Try adding  `$ = jQuery;` above all your scroll code. If that doesn't work replace all `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: Any errors in the console? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @Miro, that worked! Thank you very much! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer to the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miro replied in the comments the correct answer - "In Wordpress you need to add external jquery or equate the dollar sign to the one already in use. Try adding `$ = jQuery;` above all your scroll code. If that doesn't work replace all `$` with `jQuery`."